# How to interpret text in generated excel file as data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc

I am using JasperReports to generate a xls file. In the file there are two columns containing URL links. But the links aren't interpreted until there is a change in a cell value. I tried to use HYPERLINK function, but ended up with the same situation:

[image: Functions not executed]

When I add space or change cell's value in any other way, I get proper links. Is there a way to make Excel (or LibreOffice) interpret url columns?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "*the links aren't interpreted until there is a change in a cell value*"? Are you asking if Excel can automatically recognize the hyperlinks?

Comment: I think he means the urls aren't underlined blue (and you can't click in them) excel is only reading them as a clickable url if he manually adds a space after the url and hits return

Comment: @unknownSPY - exactly that. Cell content is evaluated as formula only after editing